# How could I go by storing items from my database into an array, but only if that item is not already in the array?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting, skip

I need to grab categories name from my database and store them into an array, but I don't want to grab the same category twice. Is there a way to, once I grab the category name and store it into an array to skip that category and not store it any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT categoryname FROM CategoryTable
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using DISTINCT in your original query?

http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL

Answer (score 0):

If `DISTINCT` doesn't work for you (maybe you have multiple queries...), you should use your array as a set. Use this to add to the array:

```
arr[$category] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, if I understand your question:

```
  select distinct `category` from table;
```